# Image/Div turning into see-through (not transparent) in impress.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, impress.js

I'm currently messing around with [impress.js](http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/#/bored), and I couldn't help but notice that some divs or images, when put through the css of impress.js, turn see-through -- not trasparent, only see-through. For example, in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JEUU2/), the first two images are see-through, while the other two are completely opaque.

What I don't want is those two images to go see-through like that. I cannot understand what is causing only those two to be like that, while the others are in an opposite state. I tried using different pictures, inter-changing places of the pictures, changing and scaling the elements, but they don't seem to work. Although changing the 7th line in the css to `opacity: 1;` does help, but it fails to give the desired effect on the elements that are not active, which is kind of important.

If anybody with a higher knowledge than mine (I'm an idiot in these matters, by the way) could look into this, their help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

~sam97

Comment: What exactly is the expected result? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Like I said, I don't want the step-1 and step-2 images to turn into see-through images, and eventually merge with the ones behind them.

Comment: the first image is not see-through. It has an opacity of 1. The other three have opacity of 0.3. The second image is in front of the first, so thats why you can see it faded out. After clicking on the images, and they rotate, the third image is at opacity 1, while the other 3 are at 0.3, which is why the background looks whiter, and the center image is opaque.

Comment: I agree with all of wat u are saying, & I don't think u understand wat my problem is. See, the first image, the black & green one, is see-through. I can actually see the white house in the back (the third picture) through the image. Same goes for the second picture, i.e. the white house on the right. (I also noticed that u can click through the image to shift focus.) This case, however, is only limited to the first black & green image & the white house on the right. For the other two, u can neither see wat is behind the image, nor can u click through it. I hope u understand. Thnx for replying.

Comment: No offense, but you aren't understanding what it as actually doing. The black and green image isn't see-through, the white house image is. Either get Firebug for Firefox, or use the developer tools in Chrome, and examine the actual CSS of those two images, and you will see that the opacity of the black/green image is 1, while the white house is 0.3, as I stated previously. The issue is, the white house image is displayed in front of the black/green image, instead of behind. That is why you can see it.

Comment: Sorry for being late. I get it now, what you are trying to say. I was under a different impression. And if what you are saying is true, then why does the white house image come front while I clearly appoint the first image to be the black-green image? A bug in the js file I guess, or maybe I am failing somewhere. Nonetheless, I understand, atleast, what the hell was going on. Thanks for helping.